# Filter datetime by date, pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I don't know why my code is not working when there are many, many examples of filtering a pandas dataframe datetime column by date, but I can't get them to work.

My dataframe has a datetime column that does NOT have an index. I have tried to use the `to_datetime()` to make sure the Series is a datetime data type. That worked. But then I am trying to filter the 3 months out of about 9 months in my datetime  column, but keep getting key errors, oddly enough. The code samples I try do not have that issue in their examples.

Here is what I have so far. As you can see some of the commented out code are lines I tried but they didn't work:

**First attempt.** This separates date from datetime, but then I can't filter those dates shown in the `date_df`.

```
# Convert date_time column to the datetime data type, then pull only dates
date_df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(less_hot_df['date_time']).dt.date
date_df.head()

9294    2014-03-07
5221    2014-01-10
5079    2013-12-30
1682    2013-12-24
4994    2013-12-23
```

**Another attempt.**

```
# Convert to datetime type, then get all rows within some dates
date_df = pd.to_datetime(less_hot_df['date_time']).dt.date
#date_df.loc['2014-03-01':'2014-05-30']
date_df.head()
```

But this one returns a key error.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'date_time'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'date_time'
```

**Yet another attempt**: won't work because of type error "not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'. But why they are considering my `date_time` column to be a timestamp, when it was just converted to a datetime type is beyond me.

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('3/1/2014 6:00', utc= True)
end_date = pd.to_datetime('5/30/2014 18:00', utc= True)
less_hot_df.loc[(less_hot_df['date_time'] > start_date) & (less_hot_df['date_time'] < end_date)]

less_hot_df.head()

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-ae4cf597cacf> in <module>()
      8 start_date = pd.to_datetime('3/1/2014 6:00', utc= True)
      9 end_date = pd.to_datetime('5/30/2014 18:00', utc= True)
---> 10 less_hot_df.loc[(less_hot_df['date_time'] > start_date) & (less_hot_df['date_time'] < end_date)]
     11 
     12 less_hot_df.head()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
     54         result = libops.vec_compare(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
     55     else:
---> 56         result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)
     57     return result.reshape(x.shape)
     58 

pandas/_libs/ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare()

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: This question is not entirely clear - for pandas questions, you should not include all you various attempts. Instead, you should include a sample of your data, and most importantly, a sample df, based off the input df, that mimics what would like to attain. That way, we can focus on how to get you the output that you're looking for. In this case, your main problem in communication is the lack of precise and obvious **sample data**.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a good idea. I wanted to include what I tried, so people would not suggest those ways already, but yes, a sample dataset would have helped a lot. The goal was stated, but yeah people were not clear what the original data looked like. Thanks.

Comment: It's really no problem - you should post your attempts actually, let me take that back. What was really lacking was the data. It's just really hard to devise solutions when you don't have a good visualization of what you're working with...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line before you do any sorting:

```py
less_hot_df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(less_hot_df['date_time'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean? I am using a dateframe (`less_hot_df`) that was left after I sorted by altitude (not date). Other than that there is no sorting in my code in these samples. The dataframe sorted by altitude is a necessity, as I'm trying to whittle down the dataset part by part. But not sure how sorting would interfere. Could you explain?

Comment: I didn't mean sorting in particular - it just looked to me for some reason like you were doing sorting. I just mean you should add this line before the code in the 3rd example.

Answer (score 1):

Question not clear but lets try

```
less_hot_df['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(less_hot_df['date_time'])
less_hot_df[less_hot_df['date_time'].between('2014-03-01','2014-05-30')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's new code I haven't seen. It didn't quite work, but almost, I am still getting dates in 2013 (before March 2014) and got this error `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.`. I am trying to get 3 months worth of dates from a dataframe. The column I need it from is a datetime type (it has the dates with the times right next to them).

Comment: What do you mean dates `dates in 2013 (before March 2014)`? what's the date range you are using and what do you exactly want to do? Please remember you can vary the dates in the `.between()` clause to achieve what you need

Comment: Sure... thanks. My original dataset tracks a bird migration from late summer 2013 to late spring 2014. And the parameters were looking for dates (you had those correct) from 2014-03-01 to 2014-05-30. But for some reason the result pulled dates from 2013. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found something that works:

```
less_hot_df = less_hot_df[less_hot_df['date_time'].dt.month.between(3,6)]
```

This returns only the rows between the months of March through May (the 6 is the stopping point, so it will stop at June). I guess I didn't have to convert my `date_time` column to a datetime data type after all.